# How to add approve and reject button in each row of datatable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I want to add a cross button and a tick button in each row of data table.
Below is the cshtml code:

```
<div class="content-block">
    <!-- Page Container -->
    <div class="section-full content-inner">
        <div class="container">

            <!---data23---->
            <div class="row mb-5">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4 class="font-weight-700 mb-4">Verification</h4>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="cph-verification-section p-4 mb-5">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 mt-4">
                        <table id="cphverification-datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>SLNo</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Phone number</th>
                                    <th>CPH ID</th>
                                    @*<th>Status/Action</th>*@
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>                                
                                    @*<td class="text-center">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="approve_cph"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-2" id="reject_cph"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                    </td>*@
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And given below is the code of javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "GetUserCPHListForVerification",
    method: "post",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#loading-area').show();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#loading-area').hide();
        if (data == 'There is no data for this request') {
            swal("Data Not Found", "There is no data with us for this request", "error");
        }
        else {
            var tabledata = [];
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var k = 0; k < obj.length; k++) {
                var row = {};
                row["SLNo"] = obj[k].SLNo;
                row["Name"] = obj[k].Name;
                row["Email"] = obj[k].Email;
                row["PhoneNo"] = obj[k].PhoneNo;
                row["CPHID"] = obj[k].CPHID;
                tabledata.push(row);

                var userdataRow = document.querySelector("#cphverification-datatable > tbody");
                $('#cphverification-datatable> tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + row.SLNo + '</td><td>' + row.Name + '</td><td>' + row.Email + '</td><td>' + row.PhoneNo + '</td><td>' + row.CPHID + '</td></tr>');
            }
            $('#cphverification-datatable').DataTable({
                searching: false,
                paging: true,
                info: false,
                lengthChange: false,
                pageLength: 5,
                bSort: false
            });
            $('.cph-verification-section').addClass('visible', 600);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.error(data);
        $('#loading-area').hide();
    }
})
```

When I am trying to uncomment @*Status/Action*@ data table is unable to load. So how to add buttons in data table row?

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the only thing that I don't understand is why you have static content inside the  `<tbody></tbody>` tags, and it might be a mistake where you append the code in your JS code, try this:

```
<div class="content-block">
    <!-- Page Container -->
    <div class="section-full content-inner">
        <div class="container">

            <!---data23---->
            <div class="row mb-5">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4 class="font-weight-700 mb-4">Verification</h4>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="cph-verification-section p-4 mb-5">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 mt-4">
                        <table id="cphverification-datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>SLNo</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Phone number</th>
                                    <th>CPH ID</th>
                                    <th>Status/Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$.ajax({
    url: "GetUserCPHListForVerification",
    method: "post",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#loading-area').show();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#loading-area').hide();
        if (data == 'There is no data for this request') {
            swal("Data Not Found", "There is no data with us for this request", "error");
        }
        else {
            var tabledata = [];
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var k = 0; k < obj.length; k++) {
                var row = {};
                row["SLNo"] = obj[k].SLNo;
                row["Name"] = obj[k].Name;
                row["Email"] = obj[k].Email;
                row["PhoneNo"] = obj[k].PhoneNo;
                row["CPHID"] = obj[k].CPHID;
                tabledata.push(row);
                //I commented this cause I didn't find where you used it
                //var userdataRow = document.querySelector("#cphverification-datatable > tbody"); 
                
                var code;
                code = '<tbody><tr><td>' + row.SLNo + '</td><td>' + row.Name + '</td><td>' + row.Email + '</td><td>' + row.PhoneNo + '</td><td>' + row.CPHID + '</td>'
                    + '<td class="text-center">'
                    + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="approve_cph"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>'
                    + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-2" id="reject_cph"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr></tbody>';
                $('#cphverification-datatable').append(code);
            }
            $('#cphverification-datatable').DataTable({
                searching: false,
                paging: true,
                info: false,
                lengthChange: false,
                pageLength: 5,
                bSort: false
            });
            $('.cph-verification-section').addClass('visible', 600);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.error(data);
        $('#loading-area').hide();
    }
})
```

From what I could see it seems you were appending all of the code after the `tr` you were statically creating creating another `tr` but since yo had one created with the wrong number of columns, maybe that was the reason it didn't rendered well, use the devtools of your browser maybe the content was there and it was that the html wasn't well formed
I think that only `$('#cphverification-datatable').append(code);` should be enough with no more things in the selector.

Edit for the question in the comments:

In order for you to use the
$('#approve_cph').click(); listener, such element ('#approve_cph') must exist already. I mean

- First you create the element
- Secondly, you create the listener.

But there's another solution, which is *delegated event listeners*, JQuery brings an easy way to do so.
I suggest you something like this, at the beginning of the document, or at least before the ajax call:

I don't know if you have many container-class elements, if you only have one you could add an id to it and be more specific, but don't worry we'll do it using the class container

```
$(".container").on("click", ".btn-success", function (e) {
    //Do something
});
```

You could change ".btn-success" for "#approve_cph", and if the `div class="container">` is unique, you could add an ID to it, but that's just a suggestion.

What the previous code does is,

- Attach an event listeners on click to any element with the class "container"
- Checks if the click was given in an element with class .btn-success

The previous code is very useful as you attach the listener to the container and then if the click was given in .btn-success, then the function will be executed, otherwise it will not.

As I told you, you could also do something like:

```
$(".container").on("click", "#approve_cph", function (e) {
    //Do something
});
```

But if the element with class container is unique you could assign it an id, and then use the class in delegation.

Read this short blog https://javascript.info/event-delegation, so you can understand why it is better to use event delegation when possible.

Comment: But how can I use those button events in javascript?

Comment: I have tried 
$('#approve_cph').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Hello');
}) but it is not working.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly for me. But how to remove both button once clicked and instead of button show rejected and approved?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [official Doc here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html) you can try something like this:

1. Uncomment your `@*<th>Status/Action</th>*@`
2. Add `columnDefs` to `DataTable`:

   ```
   $('#cphverification-datatable').DataTable({
       searching: false,
       paging: true,
       info: false,
       lengthChange: false,
       pageLength: 5,
       bSort: false,
       columnDefs: [ {
               "targets": -1, // A negative integer - column index counting from the right
               "data": null, // For 'defaultContent' param
               "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>" // Your custom HTML
           } ]
   });


   /* And from official Doc here the event trigger */
   $('#cphverification-datatable tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
       var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
       alert("The Name is: "+ data[ 1 ] );
   } );
   ```

I clearly can't test it, but conceptually I hope it works.

Cheers